# Sine of a finite sum of angles

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification, proof-writing

There is a formula for evaluating the function
$$
\sin\left(\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \theta_i\right),
$$
where $\theta_i$ form an absolutely convergent series. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities). How to write this down for
$$
\sin\left(\sum_{i = 1}^N \theta_i\right),
$$
and how to prove it?

Any reference to an existing proof is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\eqalign{\sin\left(\sum_{j=1}^N \theta_j\right) &= \left(\exp\left(i \sum_{j=1}^N \theta_j \right) - \exp\left(-i \sum_{j=1}^N \theta_j\right)\right)/(2i)\cr
&= \left(\prod_{j=1}^N (\cos(\theta_j)+i\sin(\theta_j)) - \prod_{j=1}^N (\cos(\theta_j)-i\sin(\theta_j))\right)/(2i)\cr
&= \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,N\}:\; |S|\ \text{odd}} (-1)^{(|S|-1)/2} \prod_{j \in S} \sin(\theta_j) \prod_{j \notin S} \cos(\theta_j)\cr}$$
the sum being over all subsets $S$ of $\{1,\ldots,N\}$ with odd cardinality.

Comment: Does the last part have a simpler form for people with engineering background?

Comment: Perhaps an example may help.  In the case $N=3$, the subsets of odd cardinality are $\{1\},\; \{2\},\; \{3\},\; \{1,2,3\}$ so $$\sin(\theta_1+\theta_2+\theta_3) = \sin(\theta_1) \cos(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_3) + \sin(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_3)+\sin(\theta_3)\cos(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_3) - \sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_3)$$

Comment: And when $N = 5$, those subsets are $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{3\}$, $\{4\}$, $\{5\}$, $\{1, 2, 3\}$, $\{2, 3, 4\}$, $\{3, 4, 5\}$ and $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$?

Comment: You forgot $\{1,2,4\}, \{1,2,5\}, \{1, 3, 4\}, \ldots$.