# Expanding a finite sum of angle inside a trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

I want to prove the following formulas:

$$\sin\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\theta_i\right)=\sum_{\mathrm{odd}~k\geq 1}(-1)^{\frac{k-1}{2}}\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots\},|A|=k}\left(\prod_{i\in A}\sin(\theta_i)\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos(\theta_i)\right)$$

$$\cos\left(\sum_{i=1}^\infty\theta_i\right)=\sum_{\mathrm{even}~k\geq 0}(-1)^{\frac{k}{2}}\sum_{A\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots\},|A|=k}\left(\prod_{i\in A}\sin(\theta_i)\prod_{i\not\in A}\cos(\theta_i)\right)$$

that can be found on Wikipedia's ["List of trigonometric identities" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#cite_note-21).

I don't understand the subset notations used in the different versions I read in the Math.SE question ["Sine of a finite sum of angles"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2834396/sine-of-a-finite-sum-of-angles) for instance.

Using the link between complex exponential and trigonometric function seems to be the easiest method.

Can someone explain me a way to prove those identities please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Done, I edited my post